# Ejabberd tls 1.2 only

Tags: ejabberd, tls1.2

I want to configure ejabberd server to support tls 1.2 only, and remove 1.0 and 1.1
Is it possibe? In  ([documentation](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/)) I did not found fow to do this

Should I define some specific chiphers for 1.2?

Any help can be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the "ultimate" guide to ejabberd and TLS encryption: https://blog.process-one.net/securing-ejabberd-with-tls-encryption/

The guide explains how to configure ejabberd by selecting the TLS / SSL protocol version you want.